# .catch is causing error in bluebird-promised mongoose code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, bluebird

I don't know why, but including a `.catch` in my bluebird promisified code throws an error. I'm either doing it wrong, or there's something I've missed.

Here's a typical snippet:

```
Event.find({classId : req.params.id, active : true})
    .then(function(events) {
        res.json({'events' : events})
    })
```

If I change that to

```
Event.find({classId : req.params.id, active : true})
    .then(function(events) {
        res.json({'events' : events})
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // do something
    })
```

then my test, previously passing fails with a `500: server error`.

This appears to me to follow the bluebird docs, and any code samples I've been able to find.

Am I doing it wrong? and where are errors in the `.find` going??

In case it matters, the process of enabling bluebird promises follows a familiar pattern, and allows use of the `.then` method like a champ:

```
var mongoose = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));
```

This is where I create the mongoose instance that is used to create the Schema for the Event model.

---

Post-answers: I've started using `.findAsync` and `.findOneAsync`, and I can catch errors now as expected.

Comment: Shouldnt u use findAsync after promisification

Comment: Test sample codes as you mentioned, it works well in my test. Maybe the mongoose version and bluebird version issue?

Comment: @zangw : can you give me your versions to allow me to verify?

Comment: @Yerken : can you help me out with that? I thought that .find in mongoose was asynchronous?

Comment: @DanielDonaldson, mongoose version, 4.4.3. Bluebird version  3.1.5

Comment: @DanielDonaldson it is asynchronous and it returns a promise, however you cannot use `catch` with `mongoose find` at least in older versions.

Answer (score 2):

As Yerken said `catch` is a non-standard feature for promises, but exists in almost all promises implementation including `bluebird`.

You can set mongoose to use `bluebird` promise and not its default one.

```
// Use bluebird
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

You can now use `catch`.

Answer (score 0):

`catch` is a non-standard feature for promises, it exists in `Bluebird` promisification but not in the actual mongoose `find` promise at least in older versions.

In this case you want to use `findAsync` instead of `find`